# AWS EC2 DNS not responding to Rails app deployment on CentOS 6 with passenger and nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, passenger, centos6

I've been using Heroku to deploy apps for a while but now learning how to do it on AWS without much success. I'm trying to deploy my simple rails app using AWS EC2 CentOS 6 instance with passenger and nginx. I've followed several tutorials including

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-passenger-with-nginx-on-centos-6-5

This was the main tutorial I followed before venturing out to other tutorials. This one uses Digital Ocean instance but I would believe it works in a very similar manner with AWS EC2 so that's why I used it. Most of the set up are the same.

2. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/aws/nginx/oss/el6/deploy_app.html
3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-centos-7 Which is the official page for Passenger.

I initially tried this one to see if the deployment worked with simple `rails server --binding=server_public_IP` but accessing the DNS `ec2-IP-.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` didn't seem to work, so I don't think that's the right way.

After going through the tutorials, I tried to access my Rails app through my AWS EC2 DNS (ec2-IP-.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com) but the page says `page isn’t working`. I looked up everywhere and it seems like this is a common problems but none of the solutions worked for me.

Note that I already opened HTTP port 80 in my security group on AWS so that's not an issue.

Please see below for my configuration of my `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` file. I run the app under `root` user and not as another user (such as deployer). Is there anything I miss that configure nginx/passenger to link with my AWS DNS? Currently, it says the page isn't working when I visit it after starting nginx service with `sudo service nginx restart`

Here is what I have set up for my `nginx.conf`

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    passenger_root /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-5.0.29;
    passenger_ruby /root/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  server {
    listen           80;
    server_name      localhost;

    location / {
      root   html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page       500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }

  }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  ec2-XXXX-.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
      root /var/www/texter/public;  #<==== texter is the repo of my Rails app
      passenger_enabled on;          
      passenger_app_env production;
      index  index.html index.htm;
    }

     #location / {
         #     expires max;
     #     add_header Cache-Control public;
     #   }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

}
```

Comment: go to your app folder and run `rails s -b0.0.0.0 -p80` as root and try to reach it.

Comment: I tried that but nothing is working in my DNS. Also tried that with `-e production` but I still get `page isn't working` error. Also if I do that then I need to stop my `nginx` service which is also running on port 80. I thought the whole idea of running `nginx` is to connect with my AWS EC2 server but it isn't doing that...

Comment: Just to clarify, you started the server and managed to reach it fine from the same machine with 'curl' but couldn't do it from the public network?

Comment: correct. I can curl the localhost:3000 inside my aws ec2 centos machine after I started the server but I couldn't do it when accessing the DNS